# Ubuntu 16.04 WYSIWYG web page editor that can change selected text background color?

Tags: html, editor

I have tried Bluegriffon but it can only change the background of a whole paragraph element, not just the selected text.

I have tried Seamonkey Composer but it seems to have a bug, it can only change the color of the selected text, but not the background color of that text.

I have tried LibreOffice Writer but it was not able to even open the page.

Any ideas for applications that can actually do it and are not discontinued?

Comment: Easy enough to do by hand, this is not an option?

Comment: There is also Kompozer. Don't know if it does what you want or not and it may no longer be supported but is still available.  There is at least one good tutorial for Kompozer and Bluegriffon.

Comment: @john Kompozer has been discontinued.

Comment: yes but it is still available and still works. I like BlueGriffon better myself but I've used both.

Comment: @john I have seen people commenting on askubuntu.com that installing Kompozer on Ubuntu 16.04 fails because of conflict of dependencies. Is it not the case? And is this feature I am asking about implemented there?

Comment: I have a Mac so I wouldn't know about that.  The tutorial I used was done on a windows machine and no mention was made of a problem. An older version of the system was probably used in the tutorial though.  Sorry.